# How to invoke API Gateway only from static s3 site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have hosted a static site in an S3 bucket with links to a REST API that I have deployed using Amazon API Gateway. Now I would like that the methods of the REST API can only be invoked from the static site.

In order to write the Resource Policy I can't allow for a static IP, because AWS is very clear that the IP of an S3 site is dynamic. The only option I can think of is enabling CORS in the API Gateway and configuring the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be the domain of the static site. But that doesn't seem very convincing to me..

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't do that anyway, as the API Gateway request comes from the browser of the visitor, not from server-side of the S3 hosting service.

CORS will restrict other websites calling your API using regular browsers, but a REST API client can call it without restrictions.

If you want to restrict access, either use an API Key (more obscurity than security) or implement a Custom Authorizor in API Gateway to authorise your clients. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html