# Restrict access to API Gateway to traffic coming from static website in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a static website hosted in a public S3 bucket with a little bit of javascript code in it. Basically what this bit of code does is sending a POST request to an API Gateway to retrieve some data from the backend. The URL of the API Gateway is hardcoded into the website.

I'm concerned about the security implications of this. In theory anyone could look into it, get the URL and run a DDoS attack or something leading to a lot of costs for me. Is there a way to restrict access of to the API Gateway to only the requests coming from the website in the Bucket? I know there are ways to restrict access to API Gateways with IAM or Cognito but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131373/how-to-invoke-api-gateway-only-from-static-s3-site

Answer (score 1):

Yes the issue is valid, but there is a solution, what I would suggest:

- Create a CloudFront distribution
- Create 2 origin, on for the S3 and one for the API Gateway
- configure an additional header in the API Gateway origin (which will be send between the CloudFront distribution and the API Gateway (no external will be able to see it)
- Set up a AWS WAF, and configure a RULE to reject all traffic which does not have the appropriate "header" that you have configured in the CloudFront Distribution API Gateway origin.
- Associate WAF with the API Gateway

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Also AWS will provide the default AWS Shield Standard to the CloudFront Distribution, which they claim prevent all kind of DDoS attacks by default for no charge